# Quickbooks integration with visual studio not working after update.?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, quickbooks, qbxml

I am using QBXML SDK to connect to quickbooks from visual studio. It was working fine and updating invoices till yesterday when I installed the quickbooks update. After Updating quickbooks, its showing the following error:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040408): Could not start QuickBooks.
   at Interop.QBXMLRP2.IRequestProcessor4.BeginSession(String qbFileName, QBFileMode reqFileMode)
   at QB_Process.API.ProcessRequests.Process(String operation, String strXML)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I received this same error while loading a project, but it wasn't Quickbooks related.  The problem and solution appear to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was with permissions and not with the update. In the task scheduler, I changed the user group to administrator and its working now...